# What wrong with my navigation controller, when going back title is not shown?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidappear

Why when I go from main viewcontroller to detail view controller and back again the main title is not shown, is there anything wrong with my storyboard?
[image]

I already tried to use viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.title = "Title main"
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.running == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning();
        }
       }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       self.title = "Main Title"

        do {
            let request =  NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ScannedVisitor")

            scannedVisitors = try moContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [ScannedVisitor]

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

user brl214 pointed out I might have dragged a nav bar onto the view controller, but I can not find it in the storyboard to delete it.

Any tips, suggestion?

[EDIT] Screenshot labels and views

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a child of navigation controller, try to set `self.title` directly?

Comment: @zcui93 nope, didn't solve my problem. I added a screenshot of the labels/views present on return to main view controller

Comment: Didn't you forget to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` and `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`?

Comment: no didn't forget it, the super. calls are there

Answer (score 0):

In parent view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
self.title = "Title Main"
}
```

Comment: @Alex has mentioned in question that he has already tried this code which you have posted